# cURL does not work on verbose mode

Tags: linux, curl

I have installed curl on a new ubuntu installation with apt-get and it behaves really weird.

When I do

```
    curl http://www.google.co.uk
```

everything work ok, but when I do

```
    curl -v http://www.google.co.uk
```

it fails with a connection timeout error:

```
    * About to connect() to www.google.co.uk port 80 (#0)
    * Connection time-out
    * Closing connection #0
    curl: (28) Connection time-out
```

curl -V shows:

```
    curl 7.21.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8o
    zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
    Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap
    ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
    Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Any clue?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure that your network connection has worked?

Comment: It works without the -v, so I think it is ok. Also, WGET works fine.

Comment: Other ideas: DNS problem, proxy, or a curl bug. Try with curl 7.22.0.

Comment: Works for me, same versions as you've got. Does it still fail?